# Tomcat does not recognize JAVA_HOME

Tags: bash, java, environment-variables, tomcat

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server, extracted JDK1.8u5 and Tomcat7, and added the following to .profile (I also tried adding it to .bashrc with similar [non-] results):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get the expected result of `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05`.  I can also run `java -version` and get the correct response from Java.  so far so good.

so now I try to startup Tomcat (tried also catalina.sh), and I get the following:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo /opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/startup.sh
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

but...  I just tried `echo $JAVA_HOME` and it worked?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is a help text in `catalina.sh`. I will quote it here:

```
#   Do not set the variables in this script. Instead put them into a script
#   setenv.sh in CATALINA_BASE/bin to keep your customizations separate.

#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.

# Ensure that any user defined CLASSPATH variables are not used on startup,
# but allow them to be specified in setenv.sh, in rare case when it is needed.
CLASSPATH=

if [ -r "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"
elif [ -r "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh" ]; then
  . "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh"
fi
```

When you starting `tomcat` using `catalina.sh`, it searching for file `setenv.sh` and **sourcing** it. It is searching in `CATALINA_HOME` or `CATALINA_BASE`.

So the better way to set `JAVA_HOME` for the `tomcat` is:

1. Create a script named `setenv.sh` in the folder `CATALINA_BASE/bin`, if it does not exist already.
2. Add this line to `setenv.sh`

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05
   ```
3. Make it executable.

---

### Why you should use this solution:

Setting environment variable in script is safer. Always try to set variables as locally as possible. Try do not use `/etc/environment`, `/etc/profile` and others if you really **do not** need `Global Environment Variable`. Setting `JAVA_HOME` in `setenv.sh` gives you ability to use different tomcats with different applications that need different version of `java`, but running by one user. Other user environment would not be affected by you.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have set the environment variable for your own user and not for the superuser, you have two options:

1. You will have to export the variable using `-E` option as follows:

   ```
   sudo -E /opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/startup.sh
   ```

   Note that this will export all environment variables while running the command. This is not preferred since the normal users environment is spilled out when you run the command as root. This is not desirable.
2. Export the variable in <strike>root's `.bashrc`</strike> `/etc/enviroment` file. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```

   and enter your administrative password, and add the following lines to the end of the file:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05
   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
   ```

   and then

   ```
   source /etc/environment
   ```

   or restart your machine and then retry the command you were using.

---

**Update:**

This answer provided hints as two why step 2 wouldn't work, `sudo` would reset the environment and provide a secure path, so all global variables are reset. A workaround would be to use

```
sudo su
```

and then execute command which uses the set environment variables.

Comment: Thanks @Jobin -- option 1 works so I upvoted your answer. I will now check option 2, which is my preferred solution, and if it works I will accept your answer.

Comment: I added the commands to `/root/.bashrc` with nano, as you suggested, but calling `user@ubuntu:~$ source /root/.bashrc` results in `-bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied` and trying it with sudo yields `sudo: source: command not found`.  retrying the original command at this point brings me back to point 0.

Comment: @Igal: Edited my answer to solve that issue, you should first use `sudo -i` before you `source`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: ok, pardon the newbie questions, but how do I exit the `sudo -i` once I'vet called source?  without exiting I am getting the original error message...

Comment: @Igal: Just press Ctrl + d or type `exit`.

Comment: did that...  but am still getting the original `Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined` :s

Comment: @Igal: Have modified my answer to reflect global environments file. Check if this helps, sorry for the incorrect file usage.

Comment: thank you for your patience...  I made the changes to `/etc/environment` and called `source /etc/environment` but still getting the original error message...

Comment: @Igal: `/etc/environement` variables are also reset, you would need to use `sudo su` and then run the `/opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/startup.sh`.

Comment: @Jobim thank you for your time and help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think that I see the problem. according to [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) the `/etc/environment` *is not a script* and so the `export` command in it was causing problems.

Comment: @Igal: Oh yes, it can be, can you confirm if that works? Thanks!

Comment: YES!  it worked :)  but `source /etc/environment` was not enough.  I had to reboot the server.  thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for is in `/etc/environment` which, as specified at [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables), does not process scripts and does not expand variables, so adding the following (*without* export) did the trick:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_05
```

Then I rebooted the system for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

I added JAVA_HOME in `tomcat7.service` script as `setenv.sh` was not get sourced by `catalina.sh`

**Steps:**

1.Open tomcat7 service script file

`sudo gedit /etc/init.d/tomcat7`

2.Set JAVA_HOME

```
.
.
.
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

# Directory where the Tomcat 6 binary distribution resides
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/$NAME

# Directory for per-instance configuration files and webapps
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/$NAME

# Use the Java security manager? (yes/no)
TOMCAT7_SECURITY=no
```

3.Start tomcat7 service

`sudo service tomcat7 status`

Answer (score 0):

Choose or try a different *JDK*.

Set *$JAVA_HOME* as described in the *catalina.sh* intro or other Tomcat documentation, and do not alter anything else apart from the environment variables defined therein (e.g. Catalina Home/Base). Then run the following;

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javadoc
sudo update-alternatives --config javap
```

On each one, I had to switch down from version 11 to version 8 of the Java Development Kit/JDK, for tomcat version 8. I tested twice, and I am sure this was the solution (with update alternatives, Java dependent programs know where to find Java so you don't have to repeat in the env vars file). A Initially, I did find that my shutdown.sh script was looking for my server at port 8005 while it was started at 8080 (*Severe could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running*. Or *connection refused error*). But the server itself did shutdown. I manually started it back up again, and shut it back down only to find that the error was not a reoccurring one.

Join the tomcat users group, I think you will see that Tomcat alone can be a headache. Then be patient with yourself!

NB/CAVEAT: test one change at a time, and update others accordingly.